# How to deploy an arm template from Azure storage?

Tags: azure

Can anyone advise the right syntax in powershell to deplly templates stored in a storage account to azure

I have tried the following
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ExampleDeployment -ResourceGroupName ExampleResourceGroup `
-TemplateUri https://azurefiles.core.windows.net/azuredploy.json
-TemplateParameterUri :https://azurefiles.core.windows.net/azuredploy.parameters.json

But i get an error Message=Unable to download content?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a SAS token with appropriate permissions (read) and append that to the url to be able to deploy the template using "protected" storage. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-powershell-sas-token

another option - make those URLs publicly accessible.

Comment: That worked great but i have custom scripts which deploy with the template. I uploaded the custom scripts to a container called customscripts. How can i refer to the whole container where the scripts are rather than just one file?                                                 
The custom scripts use the _artifactsLocation parameter and _artifactsLocationSASToken. How can i pass these parameters too

Comment: thats a bit of different question. i suggest you accept this answer and start a new one